# Counting the occurrence of a specific letter within a string (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, string

I have a field which contains a series of words separated by commas.

I am wondering if it is possible to count the number of times the letter 'G' occurs. Alternatively it might be possible to split the field by commas and go down another avenue...

Here's a few example fields:

- Urban,Green,Urban,Green,Green
- Urban,Urban,Urban,Urban,Green,Urban
- Urban,Green,Green

Essentially I would like to produce a new column which tells me how many times 'Green' appears in each field.

Comment: Both of those things are easily possible in Python. What have you attempted?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any and I try and do everything via field calculator. I would do it within Excel by 'find' and cutting all non 'g' characters, counting the string and then saving as a dbf but I no longer have the version of excel that saves as dbf. I am willing to try and learn if you know of any links that might help me get going :)!

Comment: I've just answered with a method like your Excel method. It uses `regexp_replace`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
array_length(
    array_filter(
        string_to_array("FIELD_NAME"),
        @element='Green'
    )
)
```

Change `FIELD_NAME` into your field name. If string is separated by another character, you should add that character to `string_to_array` function as seperator. For example:

```
string_to_array("FIELD_NAME", ';')
```

For `Urban,Green,Urban,Green,Green` string:

- `string_to_array("FIELD_NAME")` returns `['Urban', 'Green', 'Urban', 'Green', 'Green']`
- `array_filter(ARRAY, @element='Green')` returns `['Green', 'Green', 'Green']`
- `array_length` returns `3`

Comment: Thank you, this is another cracking route to the answer and I now understand what yet more functions do :)!

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way to find the number of `G`s. Replace everything that isn't a G with an empty string, and count the length of what is left:

```
length(regexp_replace('Urban,Green,Urban,Green,Green','[^G]',''))
-> 3

length(regexp_replace('Urban','[^G]',''))
-> 0
```

`[^G]` is a regexp pattern that matches any character that isn't a `G`.

Answer (score 8):

It might be simpler ways of doing it, but I would have done it by a custom function in the field calculator.

Open the attribute table for your layer. Open the field calculator (Ctrl-I or abacus icon)

Go to edit function. In the upper edit field, delete what is there and write

```
 from qgis.core import *
 from qgis.gui import *

 @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
 def cnt(field, substring, feature, parent):
     return field.count(substring)
```

Press Save and load functions,

Go back to the expression editor and write

```
cnt(<fieldname>,<searchstring>)
```

Define a fieldname and press Done.

Answer (score 7):

This expression should work:

```
array_length( 
    array_remove_all(
        array_foreach( 
        string_to_array( "column_name" ),

            array_find( string_to_array( @element ), 'Urban' )

        ),
        -1
    )
)
```

It turns turns a comma separeted sequence of strings, for example Urban,Green,Urban,Green,Green into an array.

Then it checks each element if it contains the string 'Urban', outputing an array where -1 means the element is not the string 'Urban'.

Then it creates a new array without the -1 elements, and finally counts the length of that array to get the instances of the search string.

Just replace the string 'Urban' with whatever you want to count.